# Change the selected colour of combo box in delphi firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have created application using Delphi 11.2 firemonkey for windows. In that i'm using Combobox. When the list opens, the background color of the items is blue by default, I would like to change this color

change the background color of the items

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Steve, changing style for the combobox item style is really hard. You have to, first, access to the underlying listbox (hiden in the TCustomComboBox parent), and then change the ListboxItemStyle.ActiveStyleObject (I guess). This is not a good way I think.

I prefer a different approach : using a TEdit joined to a TlistView (or a Tlistbox)
[my French blog here](https://www.developpez.net/forums/blogs/138527-sergiomaster/b7012/fmx-combobox-aux-petits-oignons/)
this way it's easy to play with colors (look at some others posts in the same blog)

Comment: I don't understand why it's so complicated to do such simple things in FMX, but anyway, thank you all for the answers.

Comment: There are some things easy to manipulate in styles, but not all. When involving StyleObjects (links to the png) it's really uneasy. 
For combobox it's more difficult because you have first to access the hidden Listbox. 
(hacking or helper to TCustomComboBox recommanded)